# What does boost::locale::generator need?

Tags: c++, boost, locale, linker-errors

I'm pretty new to boost and want to use it's boost::locale to make suitable conversations to lower case. But I've got a link problem with boost::locale::generator. I linked my project with libboost_locale-mt.a and switched header search paths correctly, but it isn't enough for some reason. I'm using Xcode, and I got linking mistake on this code:

```
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    using namespace boost::locale;
    using namespace std;

   generator gen;
   std::locale loc = gen("");
   locale::global(loc);
   cout.imbue(loc);
   cout << "This is lower case " << to_lower("Hello World!") << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the actual text of the linker error you're encountering? To make sure we help with the right thing.